# Azure Compute Emulator will not start

Tags: azure

I have recently upgraded to the new Azure SDK (September 2011 v 1.5).

Ever since I have not been able to start the compute emulator.  Consequently I can't debug the services on my local machine.

I have seen a suggestion that the problem lies with the fact that my user account has a space in it, so I renamed my account but that didn't make any difference.  It may be that the problem is that my user profile path has a space in it.  Changing the account name has no effect no the profile path.

On the msdn forums it was suggested that I remove *:808 binding in IIS Manager for Default Website. [See MSDN Forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsazuredevelopment/thread/3e36d43c-cdfe-4603-9001-ffa8f5003ed4)

Anyone have any other ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Another option:**

So, given the "rename your user account/regedit doesn't work for you, you may want to look at [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh472165.aspx), which suggests you can just set an environment variable and run the emulator without mucking with the registry... not sure if setting the environment variable globally would let you run automatically within VS.NET without manually starting up the emulator the first time, but it is certainly easier.

Comment: This is the same trick we used to use when the path name got too long.  It works just fine with Visual Studio and should fix the space in path issue (as well as path too long!).  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jnak/archive/2010/05/26/9942481.aspx

Comment: Thanks again Doug.  This worked perfectly.  I have awarded you both the answer and the bounty.  I feel that this is a much better solution as it involves a lot less messing around with your machine and so less chance of any side effects.

Comment: Sadly the MSDN link in the answer is now broken

Comment: This seems to be the current documentation: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-use-emulator/  specifically the "Start and initialize the storage emulator" section.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the space(s) in your profile path are the issue, and this appears to be a regression for a bug that was found in a previous version of the emulator (the only reason I even thought to try logging in with a different account in the first place).  I was literally just putting together a quick blog post [here](http://jeetkundoug.wordpress.com/2011/09/20/windows-azure-1-5-compute-emulator-wont-start-and-fix/) describing the same issue.  You'll need to do some registry editing to fix all the references to your old profile path if you want to fix it, or just create a new user if you can deal with re-installing software (I love the Web Platform Installer, but I found out during this exercise that it doesn't do a good job installing for "all users").

Comment: +1 Doug I am not really happy with the solution you have offered but have upvoted your answer anyway as I feel you definitely deserve some points.  It may yet turn out to be the only solution but I have awarded a bounty to see if I can drum up some interest and get a better fix.

Comment: Doug I just read that last comment again and it sounded a little harsh and wasn't meant like that.  Thanks for your hard work.