# How to start Azure Storage Emulator from within a program

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage

I have some unit tests that use Azure Storage.  When running these locally, I want them to use the Azure Storage emulator which is part of the Azure SDK v1.5.  If the emulator isn't running, I want it to be started.

To start the emulator from the command line, I can use this:

```
"C:\Program Files\Windows Azure SDK\v1.5\bin\csrun" /devstore
```

This works fine.

When I try to start it using this C# code, it crashes:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
...
ProcessStartInfo processToStart = new ProcessStartInfo() 
{   
    FileName = Path.Combine(SDKDirectory, "csrun"),
    Arguments = "/devstore"
};
Process.Start(processToStart);
```

I've tried fiddling with a number of ProcessStartInfo settings, but nothing seems to work.  Is anybody else having this problem?

I've checked the Application Event Log and found the following two entries:

**Event ID: 1023**
.NET Runtime version 2.0.50727.5446 - Fatal Execution Engine Error (000007FEF46B40D2) (80131506)

**Event ID: 1000**
Faulting application name: DSService.exe, version: 6.0.6002.18312, time stamp: 0x4e5d8cf3
Faulting module name: mscorwks.dll, version: 2.0.50727.5446, time stamp: 0x4d8cdb54
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00000000001de8d4
Faulting process id: 0x%9
Faulting application start time: 0x%10
Faulting application path: %11
Faulting module path: %12
Report Id: %13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled all of the Windows Azure bits:

- WA SDK v1.5.20830.1814
- WA Tools for Visual Studio: v1.5.40909.1602
- WA AppFabric: v1.5.37
- WA AppFabric: v2.0.224

Then, I downloaded and installed everything using the unified installer.  Everything came back except the AppFabric v2.  All the version numbers are the same.  Reran my tests and still having a problem.

And then...(this is weird)...it would work every now and then.  Rebooted the machine and now it works.  Have shutdown and rebooted a number of times now...and it just works.  (sigh)

Thanks to everyone who provided feedback and/or ideas!

The final code is:

```
    static void StartAzureStorageEmulator()
    {
        ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
        {
            FileName = Path.Combine(SDKDirectory, "csrun.exe"),
            Arguments = "/devstore",
        };
        using (Process process = Process.Start(processStartInfo))
        {
            process.WaitForExit();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 27):

**Updated 7/12/2022:**

If you are running Visual Studio 2022, `azurite.exe` is [the replacement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azurite) for the [now-deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-emulator) `AzureStorageEmulator.exe` which can be found here:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Azure Storage Emulator\azurite.exe
```

**NB**: if you are running Professional (or another) Edition, you'll need to replace `Community` with `Professional` (or the appropriate edition name) in the path.

**Updated 1/19/2015:**

After doing more testing (i.e., running several builds), I've discovered that `WAStorageEmulator.exe`'s [status API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg433005.aspx) is actually broken in a couple of significant ways (which may or may not have impact on how you use it).

The status reports `False` even when an existing process is running *if* the user differs between the existing running process and the user used to launch the status process. This incorrect status report will lead to a failure to launch the process that looks like this:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator>WAStorageEmulator.exe status
```

> ```
> Windows Azure Storage Emulator 3.4.0.0 command line tool
> IsRunning: False
> BlobEndpoint: http://127.0.0.1:10000/
> QueueEndpoint: http://127.0.0.1:10001/
> TableEndpoint: http://127.0.0.1:10002/
> ```

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator>WAStorageEmulator.exe start
```

> ```
> Windows Azure Storage Emulator 3.4.0.0 command line tool
> Error: Port conflict with existing application.
> ```

Additionally, the status command appears only to report the endpoints specified in `WAStorageEmulator.exe.config`, not those of the existing running process. I.e., if you start the emulator, then make a change to the config file, and then call status, it will report the endpoints listed in the config.

Given all of these caveats, it may, in fact, simply be better to use the original implementation as it appears to be more reliable.

I will leave both so others can choose whichever solution works for them.

**Updated 1/18/2015:**

I have fully rewritten this code to properly leverage `WAStorageEmulator.exe`'s [status API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg433005.aspx) per @RobertKoritnik's request.

```
public static class AzureStorageEmulatorManager
{
    public static bool IsProcessRunning()
    {
        bool status;

        using (Process process = Process.Start(StorageEmulatorProcessFactory.Create(ProcessCommand.Status)))
        {
            if (process == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Unable to start process.");
            }

            status = GetStatus(process);
            process.WaitForExit();
        }

        return status;
    }

    public static void StartStorageEmulator()
    {
        if (!IsProcessRunning())
        {
            ExecuteProcess(ProcessCommand.Start);
        }
    }

    public static void StopStorageEmulator()
    {
        if (IsProcessRunning())
        {
            ExecuteProcess(ProcessCommand.Stop);
        }
    }

    private static void ExecuteProcess(ProcessCommand command)
    {
        string error;

        using (Process process = Process.Start(StorageEmulatorProcessFactory.Create(command)))
        {
            if (process == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Unable to start process.");
            }

            error = GetError(process);
            process.WaitForExit();
        }

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(error))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(error);
        }
    }

    private static class StorageEmulatorProcessFactory
    {
        public static ProcessStartInfo Create(ProcessCommand command)
        {
            return new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\WAStorageEmulator.exe",
                Arguments = command.ToString().ToLower(),
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true
            };
        }
    }

    private enum ProcessCommand
    {
        Start,
        Stop,
        Status
    }

    private static bool GetStatus(Process process)
    {
        string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        string isRunningLine = output.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).SingleOrDefault(line => line.StartsWith("IsRunning"));

        if (isRunningLine == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return Boolean.Parse(isRunningLine.Split(':').Select(part => part.Trim()).Last());
    }

    private static string GetError(Process process)
    {
        string output = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
        return output.Split(':').Select(part => part.Trim()).Last();
    }
}
```

And the corresponding tests:

```
[TestFixture]
public class When_starting_process
{
    [Test]
    public void Should_return_started_status()
    {
        if (AzureStorageEmulatorManager.IsProcessRunning())
        {
            AzureStorageEmulatorManager.StopStorageEmulator();
            Assert.That(AzureStorageEmulatorManager.IsProcessRunning(), Is.False);
        }

        AzureStorageEmulatorManager.StartStorageEmulator();
        Assert.That(AzureStorageEmulatorManager.IsProcessRunning(), Is.True);
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class When_stopping_process
{
    [Test]
    public void Should_return_stopped_status()
    {
        if (!AzureStorageEmulatorManager.IsProcessRunning())
        {
            AzureStorageEmulatorManager.StartStorageEmulator();
            Assert.That(AzureStorageEmulatorManager.IsProcessRunning(), Is.True);
        }

        AzureStorageEmulatorManager.StopStorageEmulator();
        Assert.That(AzureStorageEmulatorManager.IsProcessRunning(), Is.False);
    }
}
```

**Original post:**

I took Doug Clutter's and Smarx's code one step further and created a utility class:

The code below has been updated to work on both Windows 7 and 8 and now points at the new storage emulator path as of SDK 2.4.**

```
public static class AzureStorageEmulatorManager
{
    private const string _windowsAzureStorageEmulatorPath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\WAStorageEmulator.exe";
    private const string _win7ProcessName = "WAStorageEmulator";
    private const string _win8ProcessName = "WASTOR~1";

    private static readonly ProcessStartInfo startStorageEmulator = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = _windowsAzureStorageEmulatorPath,
        Arguments = "start",
    };

    private static readonly ProcessStartInfo stopStorageEmulator = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = _windowsAzureStorageEmulatorPath,
        Arguments = "stop",
    };

    private static Process GetProcess()
    {
        return Process.GetProcessesByName(_win7ProcessName).FirstOrDefault() ?? Process.GetProcessesByName(_win8ProcessName).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public static bool IsProcessStarted()
    {
        return GetProcess() != null;
    }

    public static void StartStorageEmulator()
    {
        if (!IsProcessStarted())
        {
            using (Process process = Process.Start(startStorageEmulator))
            {
                process.WaitForExit();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void StopStorageEmulator()
    {
        using (Process process = Process.Start(stopStorageEmulator))
        {
            process.WaitForExit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This would be even better if you used **WAStorageEmulator status** instead of checking whether process is running. It would make it OS version independent (regardless how process is named) and future proof in case process name changes in the future (i.e. Windows 10).

Comment: Agreed. I didn't have the time to figure out how to capture and parse the output. Feel free to edit my answer or post a new one!

Comment: @RobertKoritnik unfortunately, it appears that the status API is of limited use in the real world... see my updated answer.

Comment: @DavidPeden the original worked perfect for me, thank you!! only thing I had to add - I've set `UseShellExecute = false` for `ProcessStartInfo` configurations as it was failing when being called from under **Global.asax.cs**, and you already have that set under new implementation.

Answer (score 4):

This program worked fine for me. Give it a try, and if it works for you too, work backwards from there. (What about your app is different from this?)

```
using System.Diagnostics;
public class Program
{
public static void Main() {
        Process.Start(@"c:\program files\windows azure sdk\v1.5\bin\csrun", "/devstore").WaitForExit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for confirming it works on your machine, but your code crashes in the same way on my machine.

Comment: So if you open up a command prompt and run that code, csrun crashes, but if you run "csrun /devstore" from the same prompt, it works? That's really strange. What OS? Anything special about the user you're running as?

Comment: does the username have a space in it?  This could be related to the problem I have been having here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7480910/azure-compute-emulator-will-not-start

Comment: @smarx - As indicated in the OP, I am running this code during the Unit Test setup.  As a test, I ran your program as a stand-alone console app and it works just fine.  Obviously, something is happening when I run the unit tests, but I haven't a clue what it might be nor why it would cause the crash.

Comment: @DavidSteele - Thanks for the suggestion David. No space in the username.

Answer (score 2):

The file name in v4.6 is "AzureStorageEmulator.exe". The full path is: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\AzureStorageEmulator.exe"

Answer (score 2):

For Windows Azure Storage Emulator v5.2, the following helper class can be used to start the emulator:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

public static class StorageEmulatorHelper {
    /* Usage:
     * ======
       AzureStorageEmulator.exe init            : Initialize the emulator database and configuration.
       AzureStorageEmulator.exe start           : Start the emulator.
       AzureStorageEmulator.exe stop            : Stop the emulator.
       AzureStorageEmulator.exe status          : Get current emulator status.
       AzureStorageEmulator.exe clear           : Delete all data in the emulator.
       AzureStorageEmulator.exe help [command]  : Show general or command-specific help.
     */
    public enum StorageEmulatorCommand {
        Init,
        Start,
        Stop,
        Status,
        Clear
    }

    public static int StartStorageEmulator() {
        return ExecuteStorageEmulatorCommand(StorageEmulatorCommand.Start);
    }

    public static int StopStorageEmulator() {
        return ExecuteStorageEmulatorCommand(StorageEmulatorCommand.Stop);
    }

    public static int ExecuteStorageEmulatorCommand(StorageEmulatorCommand command) {
        var start = new ProcessStartInfo {
            Arguments = command.ToString(),
            FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\AzureStorageEmulator.exe"
        };
        var exitCode = executeProcess(start);
        return exitCode;
    }

    private static int executeProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo) {
        int exitCode = -1;
        try {
            using (var proc = new Process {StartInfo = startInfo}) {
                proc.Start();
                proc.WaitForExit();
                exitCode = proc.ExitCode;
            }
        }
        catch {
            //
        }
        return exitCode;
    }
}
```

[Thanks to huha for the boilerplate code to execute a shell command.]

Answer (score 1):

FYI - The 1.6 default location is C:\Program Files\Windows Azure Emulator\emulator as stated on the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg433001.aspx).

Comment: And now (v1.8) it's moved again: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\Emulator\csrun.exe

Answer (score 1):

We are running into the same issue. We have the concept of a "smoke test" which runs between groups of tests, and which ensure the environment is in a good state before the next group starts. We have a .cmd file that kicks off the smoke tests, and it works just fine starting the devfabric emulator, but the devstore emulator only runs as long as the .cmd process runs.

Apparently the implementation of the DSServiceSQL.exe is different than DFService.exe. DFService seems to run like a windows service - kick it off, and it keeps running. DSServiceSQL dies as soon as the process that started it dies.

Comment: I had to add an extra parameter to the processStartInfo - UseShellExecute = false - an exception message told me to add it, and seemingly it now works.

Answer (score 0):

maybe caused by file not found?

try this

```
FileName = Path.Combine(SDKDirectory, "csrun.exe")
```

Comment: Thanks but that's not the case. The Storage Emulator actually starts and then immediately crashes. I edited the post to include information from the Application Event Log. Also, my first attempt did include the ".exe" as you suggested, but it behaved the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Here we go: Pass the string "start" to the method ExecuteWAStorageEmulator().
The NUnit.Framework is used for the Assert only.

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using NUnit.Framework;

private static void ExecuteWAStorageEmulator(string argument)
{
    var start = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        Arguments = argument,
        FileName = @"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\Storage Emulator\WAStorageEmulator.exe"
    };
    var exitCode = ExecuteProcess(start);
    Assert.AreEqual(exitCode, 0, "Error {0} executing {1} {2}", exitCode, start.FileName, start.Arguments);
}

private static int ExecuteProcess(ProcessStartInfo start)
{
    int exitCode;
    using (var proc = new Process { StartInfo = start })
    {
        proc.Start();
        proc.WaitForExit();
        exitCode = proc.ExitCode;
    }
    return exitCode;
}
```

See also my new self-answered [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22937419/1051244)

Answer (score 0):

There's now a neat little NuGet package to assist with starting/stopping the Azure Storage Emulator programmatically: [RimDev.Automation.StorageEmulator](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RimDev.Automation.StorageEmulator/).

The source code is available in [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/ritterim/automation-storage-emulator), but you can essentially do things like this:

```
if(!AzureStorageEmulatorAutomation.IsEmulatorRunning())
{
    AzureStorageEmulatorAutomation emulator = new AzureStorageEmulatorAutomation();
    emulator.Start();

    // Even clear some things
    emulator.ClearBlobs();
    emulator.ClearTables();
    emulator.ClearQueues();

    emulator.Stop();
}
```

It feels like the cleanest option to me.