# .Net Class Library Unit Test Setup Step for All Tests called only once

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, installation, azure-storage

I have a class library and associated test library. The class library needs to have the Windows Azure Storage emulator started at the beginning of the run regardless of how many classes or tests are executed. I see the base test class but that is called for every class. I need something more akin to a global class that is only called once at the beginning.

This question is in relation to this Azure Storage Emulator setup for testing: [How to start Azure Storage Emulator from within a program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7547567/how-to-start-azure-storage-emulator-from-within-a-program)

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Professional. The class library is .Net Framework 4.

Comment: Please specify which unit testing library you are using. The answer will depend on that. (NUnit, XUnit, MSTest, etc...)

Comment: This is the included library: Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which unit testing library are you using (MSTest, NUnit, etc.)?  They all have methods of running initialization either before every test, or once before all tests.

With MSTest, the initialization code (which will run once before all tests) looks like this

```
[AssemblyInitialize()]
public static void AssemblyInit(TestContext context)
{
    // Initalization code goes here
}
```

Comment: I'm including Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting which is included in VS without adding anything so I'm assuming it is MSTest or some variant. I have 3 classes that inherit from a base class so 4 files. Where do I put this code? It's own class or c'tor of base class or somewhere else.

Comment: The `AssemblyInitialize()` attribute marks code that should be run when the assembly is loaded, i.e., it will run before all test classes defined in the same assembly.  There is also `ClassInitialize()` which will run before any tests in a single class (which you could put in a base class).  See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243147.aspx) for the full documentation.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using nUnit you can create a **TestFixture** class that all your test class can inherit. inside you TestFixture create a setup method with **TestFixtureSetUp** attribute, inside that setup you can start Azure storage Emulator

http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=fixtureSetup&r=2.2.10