# Running Azure Storage Emulator programmatically

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, asp.net-core-2.1, azure-storage-emulator

I'm using an Azure Blob Storage for storing photos. It works fine. To connect to the storage I added an AzureStorageConfig in my `appsettings.json`:

```
"AzureStorageConfig": {
    "AccountName": "<accountname>",
    "ImageContainer": "<containername>",
    "AccountKey": "<accountkey>"
}
```

I additionally created a class `AzureStorageConfig`

```
 public class AzureStorageConfig
    {
        public string AccountKey { get; set; }
        public string AccountName { get; set; }
        public string BaseUrl { get; set; }
        public Uri BlobEndpoint { get; set; }
        public string ImageContainer { get; set; }
        public Uri QueueEndpoint { get; set; }
        public Uri TableEndpoint { get; set; }
    }
```

and configured it in the Startup.cs:

```
services.Configure<AzureStorageConfig>(Configuration.GetSection(nameof(AzureStorageConfig)));
```

So the config can be injected via dependency injection.

For the `appsettings.development.json` I'd like to use the Azure Storage Emulator. I found several tutorials but all of them use a connection string to connect to the emulator and not a config.

I tried with the data I found on the Microsoft pages:

```
     "AzureStorageConfig": {
    "AccountName": "devstoreaccount1",
    "ImageContainer": "images",
    "AccountKey": "Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==",
    "BlobEndpoint": "http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1",
    "TableEndpoint": "http://127.0.0.1:10002/devstoreaccount1",
    "QueueEndpoint": "http://127.0.0.1:10001/devstoreaccount1"
}
```

I Initialize the objects like this:

```
public class AzureStorageService
    {
        private readonly CloudBlobContainer _imageContainer;
        private readonly AzureStorageConfig _storageConfig; 

public AzureStorageService(IOptions<AzureStorageConfig> config)
            {  
                _storageConfig = config.Value;
                CloudStorageAccount storageAccount;
                StorageCredentials storageCredentials = new StorageCredentials(_storageConfig.AccountName, _storageConfig.AccountKey);

                if (_storageConfig.BlobEndpoint == null)
                {
                    storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(storageCredentials, true);
                }
                else
                {
                    storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(
                        storageCredentials,
                        _storageConfig.BlobEndpoint,
                        _storageConfig.QueueEndpoint,
                        _storageConfig.TableEndpoint,
                        null);
                }

                CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
                _imageContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(_storageConfig.ImageContainer);
                _imageContainer.CreateIfNotExistsAsync().Wait();
            }
}
```

I had to start the emulator manually by starting the "Microsoft Azure Compute Emulator" app. How can I start (and initialize) the emulator programmatically for the automated tests (and also for the Azure Devops CI that runs these tests)?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Since the Storage Emulator only supports `HTTP`, I'm guessing you need to specifcy that somewhere as well. If I'm not mistaking the storage client defaults to `HTTPS`.

Comment: @rickvdbosch Thank you for your advice. I changed the config in appsettings.development.json and the creation of the CloudStorageAccount. Now the used protocol is http. Unfortunately, another exception is thrown now. I edited my initial post.

Comment: Is it possible that it is an IIS issue? Any ideas?

Comment: @Julida Try to use Fiddler to monitor these requests from Blob client to inspect issues.

Comment: @JoeyCai Sorry I didn't work during the X-mas holidays.

Comment: @PeterPan Here's the fiddler Inspectors WebView (translated from German): [Fiddler] The connection to '127.0.0.1' failed. 
Error: ConnectionRefused (0x274d). 
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException Unable to connect because the destination computer refused the connection 127.0.0.1:10000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change your code to be use Connection string which is the same as using the account name and key but it will be easier when you use the emulator by just changing the connection string to `"UseDevelopmentStorage=true;"`.

As for starting the emulator, You can check the hosting environment variable in startup.cs file for the environment:

```
   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IServiceProvider serviceProvider, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                //Start the Emulator here by initiating a new process that calls the emulator.exe file
            }
}
```

The other solution would be using a hosted service and do the same check for environment and start the emulator in the `StartAsync` and stop it in the `StopAsync`

See this link for more details [Background tasks with hosted services in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: Thank you for you answer! It's working now :-) I start the emulator in the startup like this: `public virtual void Configure(IApplicationBuilder applicationBuilder, IApplicationLifetime applicationLifetime)
        {
            if ((_hostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment()
                || _hostingEnvironment.IsEnvironment("Test"))
                && !AzureStorageEmulatorManager.IsProcessRunning())
            {
                AzureStorageEmulatorManager.StartStorageEmulator();
            }` using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18094666/9888512)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the code you provided to access the appsetting.json file in asp.net core is no problem. You could refer to this [article](https://hassantariqblog.wordpress.com/2017/02/20/asp-net-core-step-by-step-guide-to-access-appsettings-json-in-web-project-and-class-library/).

And when you upload your blob, if you always get the problem, it means that the machine exists but that it has no services listening on the **specified port**, or there is a **firewall** stopping you.

If it happens occasionally - you used the word "sometimes" - and retrying succeeds, it is likely because the server has a full 'backlog'.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I get the problem every time (I didn't used the word "sometimes"). Which service should listen to the port? How can I check this? How can I check if a firewall is the cause?

Comment: Joey Cai, @PeterPan I now succeeded in using the emulator: I had to start the "Microsoft Azure Compute Emulator" app and start the emulator manually. Now It works. But it's only a stopover, because I need the emulator to start (and initialize, if necessary) the emulator programmatically as it shall be used in the automated tests (also in Azure Devops CI!). Any ideas how this can be achieved?